# onClose for Application Level Koin module singleton

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

Currently, Koin's `onClose` method is not triggered when the application is closed.

The module is defined and initialized at the start of the application and I would like to provide some closing logic when the application is terminated and the module, no longer in use.

Is there anyway for me to achieve this with Koin? I would also not like to provide closing logic within an Activity itself since the module's functionality spans multiple activities that can be closed due to, lets say, low memory.

Comment: Android does not offer apps _any_ ability to know when they are closed at the application level.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I wonder if there's a pattern in which I can follow for cases like this. Currently I am using a global singleton with bind() and release() in which it decrements/increments counters to create/relase references once the counter reaches 1 and 0 respectively bound by onCreate() and onDestroy() callbacks in respective activities.

The only reason I am doing this is for a global set of values that I need accessed throughout my application which NEED closing and release logic when they aren't used anymore, making it hard for the cases of the application being destroyed on low mem.

Comment: "Currently I am using a global singleton with bind() and release() in which it decrements/increments counters to create/relase references once the counter reaches 1 and 0 respectively bound by onCreate() and onDestroy() callbacks in respective activities." -- for that, consider `ProcessLifecycleOwner`.